# Phpunit test Symfony constraint with dependency using ConstraintValidatorTestCase

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to unit test a constraint that has a dependency and this dependency (PaymentGateway) has others dependencies. The problem here is that the validate method always return false and any buildViolation is raised. Any suggestion how to solve this?

For now i'll replace this test with a functional one, extending WebTestCase so i can correctly get the CepValidator. I'm using Symfony 3.4.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\Cep;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\CepValidator;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Test\ConstraintValidatorTestCase;

class CepValidatorTest extends ConstraintValidatorTestCase
{
    protected function createValidator()
    {
        $pg = $this->getMockBuilder('AppBundle\Utils\PaymentGateway')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('getZipCodeInfo'))
            ->getMock();

        return new CepValidator($pg);
    }

    public function testInvalidCep()
    {
        $this->validator->validate('22222222', new Cep());
        $this->buildViolation('Cep inválido.')->assertRaised();
    }
}
```

Cep Validator

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use AppBundle\Utils\PaymentGateway;

class CepValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    protected $paymentGateway;

    public function __construct(PaymentGateway $paymentGateway)
    {
        $this->paymentGateway = $paymentGateway;
    }

    public function validate($cep, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $address = $this->paymentGateway->getZipCodeInfo($cep);
        if (!isset($address->city)) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)->addViolation();

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the `CepValidator` code as well? I don't see any exptectations of `PaymentGateway` methods added

Comment: @LuninRoman i've also tried to use `->setMethods(array('getZipCodeInfo'))` in the mockBuilder, but no success.

Comment: but where is `getZipCodeInfo` return mock? You have not provided any test data